# Listing messages with more precision than yyyy/mm/dd

Tags: google-api, gmail-api

I'm trying to get all the messages sent to a user after a certain point in time, by using the Gmail API. I've successfully retrieved messages after a certain date by using the query `q=after:2015/01/19` in the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list).

I would like to be more specific than this and specify an hour and a minute of the day. Is this possible? I ask since the [Advanced Search](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)-specification only contains the most useful operators.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a search query to list messages after a certain date with *second* accuracy.

Use the search term `after:SOME_TIME_IN_SECONDS_SINCE_EPOCH`. Gmail supports the after keyword using a timestamp instead of the yyyy/mm/dd format.

Comment: Thank you very much aloo. Tried a lot of things, but this slipped my mind :) Might I ask where you found out about this? Can't find the documentation for it.

Comment: some random corner of the internet :) I can't remember now. I do remember that it wasn't part of the docs.