# Nodejs Gmail OAuth API to get Users.threads: list

Tags: node.js, google-oauth, gmail-api

I want to get list of threads after a specific datetime, but couldn't find any way to do it.
I have stored the updated datetime in the database according to the last time the Gmail API was used to fetch the list of threads.
Then using that updated time I want to retrieve the list further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Gmail API allows you to list threads/messages after a [specific timestamp with second accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022819/listing-messages-with-more-precision-than-yyyy-mm-dd).

Let's say you want to [list threads](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list#try-it) with messages received after `Friday, 22-Jul-16 00:00:00 UTC`, you would write `after:1469145600` in the `q`-parameter.

**Request**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/threads?q=after%3A1469145600&access_token={YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

**Response**

```
{
 "threads": [
  {
   "id": "1561153ce695b9ab",
   "snippet": "Infinite Elgintensity has uploaded Gym Idiots - Spread Eagle Rows &amp; Mike O&#39;Hearn 585-Lb. Squat A montage of gym fails with... Infinite Elgintensity has uploaded Gym Idiots - Spread Eagle Rows",
   "historyId": "895071"
  }
 ],
 "resultSizeEstimate": 1
}
```